# How do you clear RootLayoutPanel in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I have Buttons attached to elements on the modules entrypoint html page using `RootPanel.get("foo").add(button)`.  If I subsequently create a LayoutPanel and attach it using `RootLayoutPanel.get.add(layoutpanal)` then the buttons cannot be clicked.  This is all fine.  If I then try and remove the layoutpanel or clear the `RootLayoutPanel` the buttons still cannot be clicked.

Any ideas how to clear this? Have I missed a step or should you simply never try and get back to using a page's `RootPanel` if you have used a `RootLayoutPanel`?

Sample code:

```
public void onModuleLoad(){

    final LayoutPanel lp1=new LayoutPanel();

    ClickPanel ping=new ClickPanel("Ping");
    ping.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor( "#fdd" );
    ping.addClickHandler( new ClickHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onClick( ClickEvent event ){
            Window.alert( "Ping!!!" );
            //lp1.removeFromParent();
            //RootLayoutPanel.get().remove(lp1);
            //RootLayoutPanel.get().removeFromParent();
            RootLayoutPanel.get().clear();
        }
    } );

    ClickPanel bong=new ClickPanel("Bong");
    bong.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor( "#ddf" );
    bong.addClickHandler( new ClickHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onClick( ClickEvent event ){
            Window.alert( "Bong!!!" );
        }
    } );

    lp1.add( ping );
    lp1.setWidgetLeftWidth( ping, 100, Style.Unit.PX, 500, Style.Unit.PX );
    lp1.setWidgetTopHeight( ping, 100, Style.Unit.PX, 500, Style.Unit.PX );

    lp1.add( bong );
    lp1.setWidgetLeftWidth( bong, 50, Style.Unit.PCT, 600, Style.Unit.PX );
    lp1.setWidgetTopHeight( bong, 50, Style.Unit.PCT, 200, Style.Unit.PX );

    Button b=new Button("Click Me");
    b.addClickHandler( new ClickHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onClick( ClickEvent event ){
            RootLayoutPanel.get().add( lp1 );
        }
    } );
    RootPanel.get("button1").add( b );
}
```

`ClickPanel` is simply overrides `HTMLPanel` implementing `HasClickHandelers`. Clicking "Click Me" opens the layout panel.  Clicking the panel ping gets rid of the layout panel, but the button "Click Me" cannot be clicked.  I've tried various options.

**Update**

Calling `RootPanel.get().remove(RootLayoutPanel.get())` removes the `RootLayoutPanel` clearing the LayoutPanel and allowing widgets on the RootPanel to be clickable. However it does causes something to get screwed up because any subsequent call to `RootLayoutPanel.get.add()` throws an 
`IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  So this is not the full answer.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the DOM with Firebug or a similar tool? Maybe there are still some "leftovers" from `RootLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Yes, there is a div left over.  I could probably go in and fix up the DOM directly, but that seems pretty brittle.  Is it a bug or am I just not using it properly? I could try posting it as a bug to the GWT project and see what they say, but I'd rather ask the question first.

Comment: This is what i use; RootPanel.get().remove(RootLayoutPanel.get()); but it does not work. And RootLayoutPanel.get().clear() also wont work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second StackOverflow question, second answer by myself.  Is that bad?

So, the first call to `RootLayoutPanel.get()` does two things; creates a `RootLayoutPanel` object, keeping a singleton reference to itself, and adds itself to the RootPanel by calling `RootPanel.get().add()`.

You can remove it using `RootPanel.remove(RootLayoutPanel.get())` however this will still leave the singleton reference to `RootLayoutPanel` which will be returned if you call `RootLayoutPanel.get()`.  Since this is not attached to anything you can't add anthing too it without throwing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

To work around this you can manually reattach the `RootLayoutPanel` to the `RootPanel` with `RootPanel.get().add(RootLayoutPanel.get())`.  Calling this even if the `RootLayoutPanel` is already attached doesn't seem to do any harm... as far as I can tell.

Comment: I add the exact same problem and used that solution. It works. However, I did not find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

How about `RootPanel.get().remove(lp1)`? (where `lp1` is the `LayoutPanel` from the code above)

Comment: No, that does nothing.  I gave it a try, but was not really expecting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use RootPanel at all?

You should try

```
RootLayoutPanel.get("foo").add(button);
RootLayoutPanel.get.add(layoutpanal);
```

RootLayoutPanel attaches itself to the document body (Although in this case it should attach to the foo element). As much as I know it takes up all the available space on the screen (or to be more precise - it takes up all the space in the browser window).

This way you will be able to use the button and have the layoutpanel.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to happen with that code, but there is no such method RootLayoutPanel.get("foo").

Comment: As to the question "Why do you use RootPanel at all?"  It's existing code that controls the layout of the page. I'm adding somethign new and want it to take over the whole screen then go away after I'm done with it.

Comment: you're right - rootLayoutPanel.get("foo") doesn't exist. I've checked in the docs. I guess that the problem is because RootLayoutPanel attaches itself to the body element. I'll have a look in the code and see what happens exactly...

Comment: Have you opened an issue for this at the gwt project page?

Comment: It seems that this is happening because of calling add function right after remove. I have debugged and have noticed that if I just put breakpoints when adding a new widget (right after removing), and wait a sec before resuming, it works fine. My guess would be that it takes some time till the change is properly propagated.

Comment: This doesn't mesh very well with my understanding of the code described in my answer.  Certainly "waitign a sec" is not a practical answer, even if it did work.

Comment: Yeah, i'm very well aware that this is not a practical answer - and is even less of a practical solution. I am starting to think that this may only happen in hosted mode.. Will check that option as well...

Comment: could you post a more complete sample... I have just found out that IndexOutOfboudnsException is thrown if you try to add the same instance of a widget two or more times to RootLayoutPanel (From what I have seen in the code this should happen whenever you try to add (two or more times) the same widget  - to be more precise, the instance of the same widget - to some other widget).

Comment: It would be great if you sent the whole code with which you get the error so that I can debug it - I believe I'm on the right track to find what exactly the problem is.

Comment: erm... Not sure what you're trying to do.  I'm quite satisfied that the answer I gave explains what's happening and the workaround required to resolve it.  Please comment on the answer if you have any questions about it.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why this is happening under the hood so that I could try to fix it. Anyway I'll open an issue because of the problem when adding the widget twice to the same parent - IMHO, this should be handled properly, not with an unhandled index out of bounds exception.